# JSON Unexpected end of input when building entity model

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to use Entity Framework Core to build a model of my database.
This is the code I'm using:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
            modelBuilder.Entity<MyModel>(entity =>
            {
                //entity.ToTable("table_name");

                //entity.Property(e => e.Prop1)
                //    .IsRequired()
                //    .HasColumnName("prop1");

                //entity.Property(e => e.Prop2)
                //    .IsRequired()
                //    .HasColumnName("prop2");
            });
}
```

Running the application gives me a "Unexpected end of JSON input" error. If I comment out everything, it works fine though.

Comment: It seems like you're missing `}`

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<MyModel>(entity =>
            {
                //entity.ToTable("table_name");

                //entity.Property(e => e.Prop1)
                //    .IsRequired()
                //    .HasColumnName("prop1");

                //entity.Property(e => e.Prop2)
                //    .IsRequired()
                //    .HasColumnName("prop2");
            });
        } < ---- here --------

Comment: Oh sorry this happened when I copied & pasted but the code builds fine.

Comment: What is the defination for `MyModel`? When did you get this error? Which line throw this error during running.